# Simplest way to host self made network game for friends?

Tags: networking, home-server

I wrote a stratego clone for my friend and I to play over the internet. It consists of a very simple server and a client that can be run on the same computer as the server. What would be the simplest way for me to host this game for myself and one other person?

I have a home DSL connection. Would I need to port forward through the router and/or get a static IP address if I wanted to host it from my home connection? Are there any free ways to host it somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need two things -

1. Get an account with a service that provides [dynamic dns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS). This allows you to have a dynamically assigned ip address, but a constant domain name. So your friends can always use the same address for your computer.
2. You need to allow traffic to your server to get through your firewall/NAT.

Comment: my linksys router automatically syncs with my dyndns.com account every hour.  It supports a few other dynamic dns services too.  You can get a free 2nd level domain through dyndns.com... like mine is something.homelinux.com.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, probably the simplest way is to configure the NAT of your router to accept an ingoing connection on a specific port.

Answer (score 1):

As `matteodefelice` as already stated you need to forward ports.

In addition, note that *some* ISPs block certain ports (to stop "home" users hosting business servers, etc) so you *might* find the relevant ports blocked (obviously, test it and see).

A static IP is *not* required, you will just need to give your **external** IP to your friends. Your IP should not change during a single live connection, but if you disconnect / restart your router / have a power cut / etc and then reconnect you may get a different IP, so you'll probably want to check your IP and maybe redistribute it to your friends for each game.